Astro.currentLocale in Framework Components for SSR
I've built an app localized by Astro's i18n routing.
To get the current locale, on server-side I use Astro.currentLocale and on client-side I use window.location.pathname with a helper function that extracts the locale string.
This works, however using window.location.pathname makes the components not server-side renderable. Therefore I'm looking for a way to access Astro.currentLocale from my framework components in SSR-mode.
Currently the Astro globale is only accessible from *.astro-files and not from script files or framework script files in SSR: https://github.com/withastro/roadmap/discussions/190
I know that I could pass the current locale string as a prop, however this easily overburdens all the subcomponents when I'd have to pass a locale prop through the entire component tree.
What is a clean solution to make an Astro, SSR variable (Astro.currentLocale) available to all script files and framework files when running in SSR?

I came across the FAQ hint on the Astro doc for sharing state between islands: https://docs.astro.build/en/recipes/sharing-state-islands/ - it states that nanostores, while are made for reactivity in client-side applications, can be used in SSR as well (if can find a use-case for it).
So I've tried using them as a sort of global-state for sharing or Astro.currentLocale in Astro SSR. This is the implementation:
i18n.ts
import { atom } from "nanostores";

// get current locale - use window on client and global state for SSR

export const currentLocale = atom<string>("en");

export function getCurrentLocale(): Language {
  if (import.meta.env.SSR) return currentLocale.get();
  else return extractLanguage(window.location.pathname);
}

function extractLanguage(path: string) { … }

Layout.astro
---
import { currentLocale } from "@/lib/utils/i18n";
import SomeComponent from "@/components/SomeComponent.svelte";

// global state for current locale
currentLocale.set(Astro.currentLocale);
---

<!-- … -->
  <SomeComponent client:load />
<!-- … -->

SomeComponent.svelte
<script lang="ts">
  import { getCurrentLocale } from "@/lib/utils/i18n";
  
  // works on client and SSR
  const locale = getCurrentLocale();
  
  // …
</script>

<!-- … -->

It works in dev mode, however I'm unsure if it will be fine with multiple users accessing the page at the same time with different locales. Wouldn't want to have the nanostore mixing locale up for requests.
